# User ratings in Google play console

Tags: terminal, google-play, gsutil

I have figured out a way to install app ratings from gsutil by giving a command in terminal.

```
gsutil -m cp gs://pubsite_prod_rev_17/stats/ratings/ratings_com._201806_overview.csv  /Users/abhishekgupta/Downloads.
```

201806 represents year and month.I want it to dynamically change it for current month and run the command daily in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Changing how you run things in the command line like this is normally known as "shell programming" or "shell scripting". In order to know how to help you, people will need to know what OS (Windows? Mac? Linux) and shell (DOS? Bash? sh?) you are using. Please update your question to let people know what kind of computer you are using.

You might also want to read a tutorial on shell scripting like [this one](https://www.howtogeek.com/67469/the-beginners-guide-to-shell-scripting-the-basics/)

For doing something daily, you might want to read about `cron` if you use a linux box.